# Converting a Scala map into Python for Spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, random-forest

As par of Random Forest example:

Here is some context

```
val forest = RandomForest.trainClassifier(
  trainData, 7, Map(10 -> 4, 11 -> 40), 20,
  "auto", "entropy", 30, 300)
```

1. I am not sure what does **Map(10 -> 4, 11 -> 40)** mean ?
2. Whats the python or pyspark equivalent for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the equivalent of a Python dictionary

So

```
Map(10 -> 4, 11 -> 40)
```

Becomes

```
categoricalFeaturesInfo={10: 4, 11: 40}
```

Comment: I am not sure if represent Random forest like this:
`model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=7, {10: 4, 11: 40},
                                    numTrees=20, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                     impurity='entropy', maxDepth=30, maxBins=300)`
Errors out saying: SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Comment: Since you are naming your arguments you'll need to specify the name for this one as well, edited above

Comment: Thanks @Nick. That atleast doesn't error out but then again I am still not sure what 10->4 and 11->40 is and the code goes into an infinite loop because I think I can't parse the data.

Comment: Sorry I thought the question was related to the the map specifically. This is intended to map your categorical variables to the number of categories. Anything not in this map/dictionary will be treated as a continuous variable. So this would indicate that the variable at index 10 has 4 distinct values and the feature at index 11 has 40.